# CSS grid side column will not contain child item

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I wish to have a pretty simple layout with a sidebar, and a main section.

I want the sidebar to adjust its width depending on the contents, but only up to a certain point so the main content is not shoved off the page, and if the width is restricted, I just want to ellipse the text. I am trying to do this by using `fit-content(20%)`, but it just will not restrict the size of the sidebar.

I have an example of this [at this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gFhfxPV404OrNdPO?preview) where I have.

As can be seen, the side text will just not stay contained even with no width, let alone if I set a larger width.

[image]

How can I do this?

```css
body {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: purple solid 1px;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(20%) 1fr;
  border: red solid 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#sidebar {
  /* width: 700px; */
  border: green solid 1px;
}

#item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="item">
        some long long long long long text text text here here here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div>Main content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

`min-width: 0` is there to prevent something called "grid blowout", which makes `#container` ignore its given width and poke out of its container.

Read more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/).

> To apply our fix, we need to make sure that there is the column has a definite minimum width instead of auto.

So we give the grid item a *definite* min_width, which is `0` in our case.

Also `box-sizing: border-box` prevents `#container` poking out of `body` because of its parent's padding. It means the elements calculate its width by its border, including padding.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: purple solid 1px;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(20%) 1fr;
  border: red solid 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#sidebar {
  /* width: 700px; */
  min-width: 0;
  border: green solid 1px;
}

#item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="item">
        some long long long long long text text text here here here
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <div>Main content</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this is what you want.